# ViewModel backing properties [kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

Looking to the code of some Google's demo app (like sunflower or Google io 2018 app) and I've noticed that for  the viemodels' backing properties they use a separate instance of the same type with a custom getter; like this:

```
private val _userData: MutableLiveData<User>
val userData: LiveData<User>
    get() = _userData
```

but why do they do that? Isn't better to directly make the `_userData` accessible?
Could it be because while `_userData` is a `MutableLiveData` they don't want the observer to be able to change the value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`userData` which is exposed to the Activity or Fragment must be immutable since the view only needs to observe to the `LiveData`. So, we need to make the actual `_userData` returns a `LiveData`.

One way is using the [Kotlin coding convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#property-names) and create two variables, `_userData` and `userData`, one is mutable and another one is not:

> If a class has two properties which are conceptually the same but one
>   is part of a public API and another is an implementation detail, use
>   an underscore as the prefix for the name of the private property.